# How to get project release dates from Microsoft Team Foundation Serve API?

Tags: api, tfs

I am using Microsoft Team Foundation Serve 2015 (NOT AZURE).  I would like to pull the start end end dates for every project in TFS. I can't figure out the proper URL to get to the release dates.  I am able to get a JSON response when using these links:

http://SERVER/tfs/ProjectCollection/_apis/projects/5004808c-8fe3-40cc-9d6c-9a5e34fe2aff/teams/

http://SERVER/tfs/ProjectCollection/_apis/Identities/711cf0d6-5922-40a6-bb20-6a851b1f44f4

How do I find the correct URL for release dates?

I tried this and some other variations of it, but no joy only page not found errors... 
http://SERVER/tfs/ProjectCollection/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=1.0

Here is the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Need a JSON output as result.

Comment: Release in tfs (or azure devops) does not have any dates. Release just deploys build results to test and prod environments. Only iterations and tasks contain start and finish date. Maybe you have some custom work item type to describe a release?

Comment: How do I get to the iterations and tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider several api calls:

For work items

1. Find work items to get dates: [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
2. Get work item: [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

For iterations

3. Find iteration for team in team project: [Iterations - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: This is great, but I need the links for Microsoft Team Foundation Serve 2015 (Update 3)

Comment: You may use it for work items and maybe for iterations. Just change end the url from "?api-version=5.0" to "?api-version=2.0". [API and TFS version mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#api-and-tfs-version-mapping)

Comment: Thanks Shamrai Aleksander, I am getting the Json response that I was looking for!